# Devise defaulting to root_path when calling custom redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Hi I am trying to prompt a password reset to my users... I am using Devise in my rails app, the logic works for checking expired passwords however when I try to redirect a user to a devise root (edit_password_path etc) they are redirected to root_path ?? How can I disable this default behavior because they can be redirected anywhere else except for devise specific roots ...

Here is my code

```
def is_password_expired?
    if current_user.password_updated_at.present? || !current_user.password_updated_at.to_datetime.between?(
        Time.now.to_datetime - 3.months, Time.now.to_datetime)

      redirect_to edit_user_password_path
    elsif !current_user.password_changed_at.to_datetime.between?(
        Time.now.to_datetime - 3.months, Time.now.to_datetime)

      redirect_to edit_user_password_path
    else
      return true
    end
end
```

So I tried creating an after_sign_in_path(resource) method and that gets me to the edit_user_path endpoint however the browser just says 
`This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.`

config.rb

```
devise_scope :user   do
    get 'login' => 'users/sessions#login'
    get 'password_submitted' => 'users/passwords#submitted'
    get 'confirmations/submitted' => 'users/confirmations#submitted'
    get 'users/sign_up_as_lender' => 'users/registrations#sign_up_as_lender'
    get 'users/registration/investor' => 'users/registrations#investor'
    get 'users/registration/borrower' => 'users/registrations#borrower'
    get 'users' => "users/registrations#new"
    get 'users/password' => 'users/passwords#new'
    put 'users/passwords/change' => 'users/passwords#update_password'
    put 'users/passwords/change' => 'users/passwords#update_expired_password'
  end

resources :passwords, only: [:new, :edit, :submitted, :create, :update]
      get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
      get 'sessions/create', to: 'sessions#new'
      post 'sessions/create', to: 'sessions#create'
      delete 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
      get 'password-submitted' => 'passwords#submitted'
    end
```

Comment: Can you post the `routes.rb` in the question?

Comment: Hi added above, but only devise routes

Comment: Where do you defined route for `edit_user_password_path`? I don't such entry in the `routes.rb`

Comment: Sorry, lets say I want to direct users to this route put 'users/passwords/change' => 'users/passwords#update_expired_password' ? Either way by default devise wont let me